# cant get samba share to work on ubuntu server vm

Tags: server, samba, hyper-v

I have a windows 2012 server running hyper v with a number of vms running and connected properly. I created a new vm for ubuntu server 15.04 to run samba as a file server. After installing ubuntu server, samba, and setting up the configure file. I cannot access the samba share on a windows 10 workstation. my firewall is off as a test, and I still cannot access the share on my win10 station

my samba config file is;

```
[Plex]
comment = plexdir
path = /var/plx
available = yes
public = yes
writeable = yes
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0755
directory mask = 0755
```

I have been migrating all of my servers to VM lately, as before everything was the exact same, but in different boxes. It seems as though now using hyperv I am having trouble. using ping, all servers can send and recieve on my network. Please help, as usally I overlook a simple step causing problems like these...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[global]` section parameters and `guest only = yes`, also remove `public = yes` and `available = yes` as follows:

```
[global]
        security = user
        encrypt passwords = true
        map to guest = bad user
        guest account = nobody

[Plex]
        comment = plexdir
        path = /var/plx
        writeable = yes
        browsable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        guest only = yes
        read only = no
        create mask = 0755
        directory mask = 0755
```

Then connect as user *nobody*, *guest* or any user not existing on the target machine.

Additionally, if you have more than one network or network card, you have to let samba know explicitly where to work by adding this lines to `[global]` :

```
interfaces = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.X.XXX/24
bind interfaces only = yes
```

substituting 192.168.X.XXX/24 as needed.

Also be sure you don't have any of this lines, which forces PAM user authentication:

```
obey pam restrictions = Yes
pam password change = Yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide

Comment: thank you for your help. I have done what you have sugguested and I still cannot access the share. Normally it should show on my network as a file, but it is not there. I try to map the drive by using "\\192.168.0.10\var\plx" but the connection was refused.  Also I've noticed that I cannot connect to any VM via SSH using putty... this sounds like a networking problem....